# is there a better alternative to mutualizing python pip packages between python versions than a manually created symlink?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

My appetite for PyPI packages seems to grow with every new minor release of Python:

```bash
$ du -hs /home/myuser/.local/lib/python*
16M     /home/myuser/.local/lib/python2.7
1.9G    /home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10
1.4M    /home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.6
7.6M    /home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.7
293M    /home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8
8.0K    /home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.9
```

As I have installed Python 3.11 earlier today on my Ubuntu 22.10 machine, I have been thinking about mutualizing the tall pile of locally installed PyPI packages, so that I don't have to eat up a few more gigabytes of disk space once more.

So I came up with the idea of creating a symlink between the freshly created directory `python3.11/site-packages` and the most up-to-date and most populated directory `python3.10/site-packages`, like this:

```bash
$ tree -L 2 /home/myuser/.local/lib
/home/myuser/.local/lib
├── python2.7
│   └── site-packages
├── python3.10
│   └── site-packages
├── python3.11
│   └── site-packages -> /home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
├── python3.6
│   └── site-packages
├── python3.7
│   └── site-packages
├── python3.8
│   └── site-packages
└── python3.9
    └── site-packages

14 directories, 0 files
```

I then used `update-alternatives` to set `python3.11` as the default Python version. So far, Python found all the packages, and nothing seems to have broken.

However, I can't help but wonder:

- What risks am I taking with this approach?
- Is there a better alternative to mutualizing python pip packages between python versions than a manually created symlink?